# Wordpress - How can I display the remaining post content *minus* the excerpt, in a separate div?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the excerpt from the post on the home page with

```
function excerpt($limit) {
    return wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
}
```

On single.php, I'd like to show this same excerpt section at the top, next to the featured image - and then the *remaining* content() in a separate div below.
I'd post what I've tried but I'm completely stumped and don't know where to start. Everything I'm seeing in searching forums is focused on creating the excerpt itself, or displaying the entire post.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like this works:

```
var excerpt = $('#excerpt').html()
    content = $('#content').html()
    newcontent = content.replace(excerpt,'');

$('#content').html(newcontent);
```

Anyone have anything better? Any reason I shouldn't go with this? The only issue I see here is the possibility of there being multiple instances of the *exact* same copy somewhere in the main body content and then that is omitted by mistake also. But in blog copy where I'm using this, this seems very unlikely.